# PHP - str_getcsv parse multiple lines | performance improvement

Tags: php, arrays, performance, parsing

I have a csv file on my server that i want to parse to a PHP-array with `str_getcsv()`.

It works fine, but recently the length of the data reached over 18.000 rows, which seems to be some sort of a limit for looping through each one of them and parsing them to the `$array`.

Is there a way to parse multiple lines in each loop (without repetition-lines ofc)? Would that help or wouldn't it work again?

Is there a general way to improve the performance of this?

```
$url = 'some/url/data.csv';
$csvData = file_get_contents($url);
$lines = explode(PHP_EOL, $csvData);
$array = array();

foreach ($lines as $line) {

    //some formatting

    $array[] = str_getcsv($line);
}

array_splice($array, 0, 1);
array_pop($array);
```

this doesn't work anymore as soon as there are over 18k rows

Comment: you're slurping the entire file into memory first, then parsing it. why not `$fh = fopen(...); while($row = fgetcsv($fh)) { ... }`? because right now you're triplicating the data. slurp in the raw file (18,000 rows worth of data), split the data into individual records (ANOTHER 18,000 rows worth of data), then build ANOTHER array with the parsed csv data, effectively causing 54,000 rows of data to be held in various temporary structures.

Comment: could you please explain this further in an own answer? :)

Comment: You basically reinvented `= array_map("str_getcsv", file($fn))` in much more code. Using a [`SplFileObject`](http://php.net/SplFileObject) would also be way less effort.

Comment: Consider http://csv.thephpleague.com/examples/